# can .off removes event handlers that were NOT attached with .on()?

Tags: jquery

My .off function seems not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#evtTarget").hover(highlight, highlight);
        $("#evtTarget").click(function(){
            $("#evtTarget").off("hover"); 
            });
    });

    function highlight(){
        $("#evtTarget").toggleClass("highlighted"); 
        }

</script>
```

I can I remove the .hover event?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `hover` event. From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

---

So try this:

```
$('#evtTarget').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: Don't understand why it's not an event. But your solution works. thank you.

Comment: There is no actual `hover` event. The jQuery `.hover()` function is a shorthand function to let you more concisely bind handlers for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: Now I should be careful that not everything listed on this page are EVENTS:http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: Can .off function be  used to remove .click()?

Comment: Yes, `click` is an event.

Answer (score 0):

`.off('hover'` isnt going to work, because `hover` is not actually a DOM event. `.hover()` is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` combined.

Therefore, you should do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#evtTarget').on({
        'mouseenter mouseleave':function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted")
        },
        click:function(){
            $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave'); 
        }
    });
});
```

This will remove the bindings for those events. I also took the liberty of caching and consolidating your code, for optimization purposes.

Comment: nope ... nor any other single-word event! the only reason its around the `'mouseenter mouseleave'` is because we are combining two events into one binding declaration. if they were separate functions, you could just do `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` without quotation marks. its also faster, because its the native DOM name vs asking the engine to parse a string before binding.

Comment: i will add ... this is because i am using the object version of the `.on()` function (hence the `.on({` before the events). if you used the more traditional version, you would need to pass a string.

Comment: by traditional i mean like using `.on('click,function...` vs `.on({click:function...`, and no worries!